# Parse String to long with leading zero

Tags: java, parsing, long-integer, zero

Long story short (in Java):

```
String input= "0888880747;

long convert = Long.parseLong(input);
```

The value of convert is now: 888880747

How can I parse the `String` to a `long` but retain the leading zero?

Comment: That makes no sense at all. longs don't have leading zeros, only Strings do.

Comment: 00001 is the same as 1. Leading zeroes have no effect.

Comment: If you want leading zeros you need to store it in a String or format it to a string when printing out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot because a long does not have a leading zero. A long is supposed to store [integers (the mathematical concept, not `int`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer), i.e.

[image: number line]

A string of characters like `05` is not an integer, `5` is. What you can do is format a long that holds `5` with a leading zero when you print it, see e.g. [java.util.Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Are you sure you even want to have a long/an integer? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Thank you.  I suspected as much, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: it means if it is written like `09` is considered as a string, not an integer and if you convert this into  integer, it will give you only '9'.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to change it back to a `String` when you've done your calculations on convert, then:

```
output = String.format("%06d", convert);
```

Answer (score 2):

A `long` is a numeric value. The numeric value of 000001 is no different from 1: It's the exact same number.

So you **can't** find out how many leading zeroes the initial representation had, once you have a `long`.

And **if** you really care about that, then you shouldn't handle the input as a numeric type anyway, but store the `String` itself, instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your value is a long, then any zeroes to the left (leading) have no mathematical value, therefore, they are stripped off when you do the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the code. First get the length of string.

```
String input  =   "0888880747";

System.out.println(String.format("%0"+input.length()+"d", Long.valueOf(input)))):
```

The above tweek works but doesn't look good. Better to read the  value as String and store in DB as varchar instead of Number if leading zeros matter.